# AngularJS insert data twice to database

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to insert data to database through angularJS but the data inserted twice.. I have tried to use ngRoute but still I face the same problem.

app.js

```
 var app = angular.module("addDepApp", []);
 app.controller('insertDepCtl', function($scope, $http) {

var isSend = false;
$scope.$on('newuser', function(event, data){
    load(true);

});


var load = function(isEvent){

    if($scope.$parent.newuser != null){
        isSend = true;
    }
};
load();

$scope.insertDepartment = function () {
    console.log("called insertDepartment");
    if (isSend == true){
        $scope.newuserSend = {'org_id': $scope.$parent.newuser.org_id, 'dep_name': $scope.department};
        $http.post("http://192.168.1.12:8888/XXXX/XXX/insertDep.php/",$scope.newuserSend)

    }

}

});
```

add.html

```
  <body ng-app="addDepApp">
  <div class="12u$" ng-controller="insertDepCtl">
  <input type="button" value="تسجيل" class="special" id="signup" ng-click="insertDepartment()"/>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: provide a demo that reproduces problem in client

Comment: @charlietfl 2 rows inserted in the database one row with empty data and the second row with data I have send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the code to this and now it works fine!!

```
 $scope.insertDepartment = function () {
    if (isSend == true) {

        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "http://192.168.1.106:8888/XXXX/XXX/insertDep.php/",
            data: {'org_id': $scope.$parent.newuser.org_id, 'dep_name': $scope.department},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `ng-controller="insertDepCtl"` from your html code, your router injects this for you. Right now, you're calling everything twice

Comment: Thank you, but I have removed the ngRoute

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: I got this error "insertDepartment is undefined" .. Please note that I am not using ngRoute

Comment: any solution you suggest?